# How can do ssh as ssh root@someserverip

Tags: superuser

I have a set up an ec2 instance , but i am able to ssh into it as ssh centos@ipaddress 
How can i ssh as root@ipadrress? I have changed the PermitRootLogin yes but that does not help.
Please suggest.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either do any one of the below,

**i)** Login using Keypair

Copy the public key of the key pair to the `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. The public key would be available in `/home/centos/.ssh/authorized_keys` (for `centos` default user). The permissions of this file must be set to `600`.

**ii)** Login using Password

- Create a password for the `root` user
- Set `PasswordAuthentication yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
- Restart `sshd` service.

Comment: you should go with option i

Comment: @franklinsijo Thank you!